# $M\otimes _k S\cong M$?

Tags: commutative-algebra

If $0\rightarrow K\rightarrow S$ is an injective ring homomorphism of commutative rings and if $M$ is an $S$-Module am I right that $M\otimes _K S\cong M$?

Comment: What is $k$? Do you mean to say $\otimes_K$?

Comment: I mean tensor product over k, since both M and S are K-module because of the ring homomorphism.

Comment: Even I can suppose that S is flat as an K-module.

Comment: You seem to use $k$ and $K$ as though they are the same. They are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is false, even in very nice cases, for instance $M=S$, $K$ and $S$ are fields, and $S/K$ is finite (even Galois).

As an example, $\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}\simeq \mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: My problem in very particular case is this: If M is an K[x]-module(K is a field), I still cannot say that $ M\otimes_K{K[X]}$ is isomorphic to M. because in this case  we know that M->M[x] is  injective.